# DIV block jumps mysteriously to the right

Tags: html, css

I seem to be having a rather unique problem with my tumblr theme. It is my first one, and first time coding in a very long time in general, and cannot seem to find out what is wrong with it.

Like on any blog block on tumblr, I have captions, notes and tags underneath my posts. Essentially, there are three levels of content; first the photo, then the caption or description, and finally the notes / tags, all layered one under the one before it.

It works fine on text, chat, quote, and link posts. It looks exactly the way it should, and I'll add a screenshot of it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxQ8h.png

On photos, photosets, and videos however, the notes and tags jump to the right, next to the photos or video. **Can anybody figure out why?** I've been scrutinizing every inch of my theme for a day now and cannot find a reason for it.

I'll add a screenshot of this as well.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntPey.png

The rest will be copy / paste of the relevant code. I would really appreciate it if someone could take a look at this.

The mark up and css bits:

```css
    #articleblock
    {
     display: table;
     width: 100%;
     margin-top: 70px;
    }

    #articlebuttons ul
    {
     display: table-cell;
     text-align: center;
     list-style: none outside none;
     width: 60px;
    }

    #articlebuttons li
    {
     padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
    }

    #articlebody
    {
     display: table-cell;
     padding: 0px 20px 0px 30px;
     vertical-align: top;
     font-family: Open Sans;
     letter-spacing: 0.015em;
     text-align: justify;
     font-size: 85%;
     width: 100%;
    }

    #bodymodel a
    {
     color: #33a4cd;
     text-decoration: none;
     border-bottom: dotted 1px #33a4cd;
     line-height: 1.75;
    }

    #articlefooter
    {
     margin-top: 20px;
     border-top: solid 1px #8d8d8d;
     display: table;
     width: 100%;
    }

    #articlefooter_notes
    {
     vertical-align: top;
     padding-left: 5px;
     width: 100px;
     font-family: Roboto Condensed;
     font-size: 90%;
     display: table-cell;
     color: #444;
    }

    #articlefooter_tags ul li
    {
     position: relative;
     top: -14px;
     list-style-type: none;
     padding-right: 5px;
     font-family: Roboto Condensed;
     font-size: 90%;
     display: table-cell;
     color: #444;
    }

    #articlefooter a:link, a:visited, a:active
    {
     color: #444;
     text-decoration: none;
     line-height: 1.75;
    }

    #articlefooter a:hover
    {
     color: #444;
     text-decoration: none;
     border-bottom: dotted 1px #444;
     line-height: 1.75;
    }
```

```html
<div id="articleblock">

     <div id="articlebuttons">
      <ul>
       <li><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/3jz0ga1/XTwnc4y6k/icon-picture.png" width="60" height="64" alt=""></li>
       <li><a href=""><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/3jz0ga1/q5cnc3thu/button-like.png" width="17" height="16"></a></li>
       <li><a href=""><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/3jz0ga1/OsLnc3thu/button-reblog.png" width="17" height="16"></a></li>
       <li><a href=""><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/3jz0ga1/DIlnc3thv/button-tweet.png" width="20" height="16"></a></li>
       <li><a href=""><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/3jz0ga1/RzSnc3tht/button-facebook.png" width="8" height="16"></a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>

     <div id="articlebody">
         <center><a href="http://jubileetheme.tumblr.com/image/97873714593"><img src="http://38.media.tumblr.com/4f36f7541c9d11a42208526b64520122/tumblr_nc4zk3LKgy1tmsy4wo1_500.jpg"></a></center>
         <div id="bodymodel"><p><span>Aenean tincidunt ac sapien at volutpat. Praesent eu diam lobortis, sagittis dolor tincidunt, rutrum nisl. Aenean molestie augue risus, eget tempus turpis eleifend nec. Pellentesque hendrerit tellus eget dui bibendum, quis varius orci cursus.</span></p></div>
     </div>
       
     <div id="articlefooter">
            <div id="articlefooter_notes"><a href="http://jubileetheme.tumblr.com/post/97873714593/aenean-tincidunt-ac-sapien-at-volutpat-praesent">0 notes</a></div>
            <div id="articlefooter_tags">
                        
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://jubileetheme.tumblr.com/tagged/mountain">#mountain</a></li><li><a href="http://jubileetheme.tumblr.com/tagged/beauty">#beauty</a></li>
            </ul>
                        
        </div>
     </div>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: A snippet contains different sections for `HTML`, `CSS` and `JS`. You already seems to know that since you posted each in the correct sections. Then why have you posted two separate snippets?  Please update it properly.

Comment: Not used to posting in stackoverflow I suppose. In the forums I frequented, it was more customary to post different parts of the code separate, for clarity. My apologies.

Comment: You are using `display: table` but the children are a mix of block, table-cell and table displays. Is there a _good_ reason for that?

Comment: Is there a scroll bar on the right of one page but not the other?

Comment: @SalmanA It is likely I don't understand fully how display: tables work. CSS was honestly never my strong suit. The idea behind the way I've laid it is that there is a table inside another table, but I see how that probably isn't working. E.g. I realized I never have separate table-rows in the article layout. Is it this that is causing the disruption?

Comment: @Rob There is a normal scroll bar on the page, to the right. You just cannot see it on the screenshots. There are no other scroll bars.

Comment: @Dannyl My question was whether the scroll bar was on BOTH pages.

Comment: @Rob There is only one page; the different types of blocks (photos, text, quotes, etc.) occur on the one, same page. So I'm afraid I'm confused by what you mean?

Comment: Woah, I have been away from SO for a while, "runnable snippets". Wow. This is fun! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is based on `display: table` but you apply block/table/table-cell displays on the children. This does not always work as expected. I have revised your CSS to use floats. `display: flex` is the way to go but right now it has limited browser support.

```css
#articleblock {
    margin-top: 70px;
}
#articlebuttons {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
}
#articlebuttons ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
    width: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}
#articlebuttons li {
    padding: 0 0 15px 0;
}
#articlebody {
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding: 0 40px;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 85%;
    text-align: justify;
    letter-spacing: 0.015em;
}
#articlefooter {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    border-top: solid 1px #8d8d8d;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#articlefooter_notes {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    font-family: Roboto Condensed;
    font-size: 90%;
    color: #444;
}
#articlefooter_tags {
    float: left;
    font-family: Roboto Condensed;
    font-size: 90%;
    color: #444;
}
#articlefooter_tags ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#articlefooter_tags li {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
/* dont care section */
#bodymodel a {
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #33a4cd;
    line-height: 1.75;
    color: #33a4cd;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#articlefooter a:link, a:visited, a:active {
    line-height: 1.75;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#articlefooter a:hover {
    border-bottom: dotted 1px #444;
    line-height: 1.75;
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="articleblock">
    <div id="articlebuttons">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/3jz0ga1/XTwnc4y6k/icon-picture.png" width="60" height="64" alt=""></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/3jz0ga1/q5cnc3thu/button-like.png" width="17" height="16"></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/3jz0ga1/OsLnc3thu/button-reblog.png" width="17" height="16"></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/3jz0ga1/DIlnc3thv/button-tweet.png" width="20" height="16"></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/3jz0ga1/RzSnc3tht/button-facebook.png" width="8" height="16"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="articlebody">
        <center><a href="http://jubileetheme.tumblr.com/image/97873714593"><img src="http://38.media.tumblr.com/4f36f7541c9d11a42208526b64520122/tumblr_nc4zk3LKgy1tmsy4wo1_500.jpg"></a></center>
        <div id="bodymodel">
            <p><span>Aenean tincidunt ac sapien at volutpat. Praesent eu diam lobortis, sagittis dolor tincidunt, rutrum nisl. Aenean molestie augue risus, eget tempus turpis eleifend nec. Pellentesque hendrerit tellus eget dui bibendum, quis varius orci cursus.</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="articlefooter">
        <div id="articlefooter_notes">
            <a href="http://jubileetheme.tumblr.com/post/97873714593/aenean-tincidunt-ac-sapien-at-volutpat-praesent">0 notes</a></div>
        <div id="articlefooter_tags">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://jubileetheme.tumblr.com/tagged/mountain">#mountain</a></li><li><a href="http://jubileetheme.tumblr.com/tagged/beauty">#beauty</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```